# Audio frequency spectrum of a video at a given time

Tags: software-rec, audio, video, scientific-linux

Is there a simple way to get the audio frequency spectrum at a given time of a video?

My motivation is the following: I was wondering if it is possible to "measure" the Doppler shift from YouTube videos like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imoxDcn2Sgo) using only my laptop.

Comment: Meanwhile I found an answer and posted it, however, I am still interested in other maybe easier or more professional solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the following solution:

1. Launch [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)
2. Open your video file say video.flv
   Alternatively you can use ffmpeg to extract the audio: 
   `ffmpeg -i video.flv audio.wav`
   and open in audacity audio.wav
3. Select a region of the waveform
4. Go to Analyze – Plot Spectrum

I think it is helpful to set the axis to `Log frequency` and use the largest value for size so select relevant peaks.